# For facebook login appId and appSecret working on staging, not working on local branch

Tags: facebook

I’am trying to get the facebook authentication to work on my local branch. I have valid appId and appSecret that works on staging branch. Both the branches have similar configuration for facebook which looks like:

```
appId: '****',
appSecret: '****'
```

Whenever I try to log in with facebook from my local branch, I get this error saying:

```
{ message: 'Error validating client secret.', type: 'OAuthException', code: 1, fbtrace_id: '****' }
```

But the same code with the same appId and appSecret works perfectly on staging.

What am I doing wrong here?